# Assistance to implement my own getElementByID()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement my own getElementById() function in Javascript. My idea/algorithm goes like this:

```
function myGetElemById(id){
    // rootNode I suppose will be the BODY tag.
    rootElem = get elements by TAGNAME (rootNode);
    elems = rootElems.getChildren();
    for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
        if(!elems[i].hasChildren()){
            myGetElemById(elems[i]);
        } else {
          if(elems[i].id == id)
              return elems[i];
          else
              return null;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to implement your own version? What's wrong with the native one?

Comment: You don't like JQuery selectors? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @karthick Objective here is to emulate the actual implementation by various browsers, I know they are different from each other. This is just to know the underlying process and how different browser implementation count towards performance and their data structure.

Comment: @JanHančič No offence to the native implementations. My motive here is to understand how different browser implementation count towards performance and their data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

```
function myGetElemById(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Method 2:

```
function myGetElemById(id){
  return window[id];
}
```

Method 3: (newer browsers)

```
function myGetElemById(id){
  return document.querySelectorAll('#' + id);
}
```

**DONE!**

Okay, seriously:

```
function getById(id, parent, list){
  parent = parent || document.body;
  list   = list   || [];

  var l, child, children = parent.children;

  if(children){
    l = children.length;
    while(l--){
      child = children[l];
      if(child.id == id) list.push(child);
      getById(id, child, list);
    }
  }

  return list;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use ant native methods available in the browsers JS scope. I am struggling to get hold of the document elements and then iterate over them to match the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this feature and maybe you can get ideas

```
function getElementsStartsWithId( id ) {
  var children = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var elements = [], child;
  for (var i = 0, length = children.length; i < length; i++) {
    child = children[i];
    if (child.id.substr(0, id.length) == id)
      elements.push(child);
  }
  return elements;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you must deal with the elements has children, call myGetElemById() and choose to return or not to return, depend on the result. like this

```
    ...
    if(!elems[i].hasChildren()){
        var result = myGetElemById(elems[i]);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    } else {
    ...
```

second why iterate over all the elements of the dom? the native function is much more faster.

Comment: I agree. This is just to understand the various implementation across various browsers, their performances and data structures. Some use MAPs based structures some use TREE. So I want to implement my own function by trying to find a sweet spot. No offence to the already available JS functions though.

Answer (score 0):

Custom get element by ID method using BFS:

```
function myGetElementById(id, root){
    let queue = [];  // Using array here but linkedList is more performant in both time and space complexity

    queue.push(root);

    let currentNode;

    while(queue.length){
        currentNode = queue.shift();
        if(currentNode.id === id){
            return currentNode;
        } 

        queue.push(...currentNode.children);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why `currentNode.attributes.id.nodeValue` instead of just `currentNode.id`?

Comment: That works too and it is much more concise.  Thanks Bergi!